# Finding a way to reach at beginning of the buffer once input is entered and reading characters one by one

Tags: c++, io

I wanted to read the buffer until `EOF` is found in the buffer and then set the  stream as corrupt or bad. If `epack()` was not a **protected member function** I could've tried this:

```
std::string s;
int position=0;
char c;

std::streambuf *buffer_obj = std::cin.rdbuf();

/*ASSOCIATING STREAM_OBJ WITH INPUT BUFFER*/
std::istream stream_obj(buffer_obj);

/*ENTER "ABC" THEN PRESS CTRL+D TO INPUT EOF THEN ENTER "DEF"*/
stream_obj>>s;          

/*LOOP STARTS FOR EOF*/
if((c=*(std::buffer_obj->eback()[position++])) != EOF)
{
    std::cout<<c;
}
else
{
    std::cout<<"EOF in buffer"<<endl;
    break;
}
/*LOOP ENDS*/
```

Two questions:

1. Had this above code worked if `eback()` were a **public** function?
2. How can I search for specific characters in the buffer since pointers are protected and I can't get `sbumpc` or `sgetc` to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer to look for specific character in the buffer =>

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main()
{
    int i;
    std::streambuf *obj=std::cin.rdbuf();
    std::istream sobj(obj);

    /*THIS ONE EXTRACTS FROM THE BUFFER ONE CHARACTER AT A TIME*/
    while((i=sobj.std::istream::get())!=EOF) 
    {
        std::cout<<(char)i;
    }

    /*EOFBIT IS SET FOR THE STREAM WHEN EOF IS ENCOUNTERED*/ 
    if(sobj.eof()==true)     
    {
        std::cout<<"EOF FOUND"<<std::endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Similarly any character can be found in the buffer and `sobj` can be replaced with `cin` and can be checked for `EOF`. For example, lets say the character one is looking for is **D** and we need to stop reading after we found **D** in the buffer:

```
int i;

while((i=std::cin.std::istream::get())!='D')
{
   std::cout<<(char)i;
}
```

so if input is `avb45Dert` then the output will be `avb45`.